# Convert a sed command into awk to work with variables

Tags: awk, sed

I have this file which contains:

```
cat file.txt
<interface type='network'>
      <mac address='FXP-MACADDRESS'/>
      <source network='FXP-BRIDGE'/>
      <target dev='FXP-INT-NAME'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

By using this command:

```
cat file.txt | sed -n '1,/0x03/p' | tail -6 | awk '/mac address/ {print $2}' | awk -F"'" '{print $2}'

Output:
FXP-MACADDRESS
```

My problem is that I was reading that `sed` does not allow variables to be used. I would like to convert `0x03` into for example `fxp0_slot=0x03` and use `$fxp0_slot` in the command.

Does anyone knows an alternative to obtain the same output but by using variables instead?

Comment: What you're asking for is not clear. If you want to replace `0x03` by `fxp0_slot=0x03` in your file, what would be the value and the role of variable also named `fxp0_slot`? Please show an example with a value of bash variable `fxp0_slot`, and your expected output.

Comment: What I am thinking of is to use the variable in a loop. There are so many changes that needs to be done to multiple files so a loop would be great. The given example is only a simple example as in reality that variable will alternate multiple times

Comment: Please show an example with a value of bash variable `fxp0_slot`, and your expected output. Please do this by editing your question, not in comments. You could also visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I was able to find the solution:

slot3=0x03

```
cat ... | awk '{a[++i]=$0;}''/'$slot3'/{for(j=NR-5;j<=NR;j++)print a[j];}'
```